# How to have code in a class run only if it's the base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way for a class to run a portion of its code only if the class called as a base class or when it's called through `subprocess()`? The code would be ignored if it's called through a subclass extension or if it's called through `super()`.

Using `__name__ == '__main__'` will not work because when it's called using `subprocess()` it will have the module's name as its `__name__`.

So for example:

module A

```
class A():
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'Alice'
```

This portion will only run if class A() is run as the base class or through `subprocess()`.
It will NOT run if it's called using `super()` or if it's called as an inherited class.

```
self.city = 'Pittsburgh'
```

module B

```
import A
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
       super(B, self).__init__()
    #Inherits self.name = 'Alice' but does NOT inherit self.city = 'Pittsburgh'
```

So in the above scenario, when class A() is created by directly calling it in module A or by `subprocess()`, it will have `self.city` as `'Pittsburgh'`.    However, if class A() is called through `super()` in module B or as an inherited class, it will only have `self.name` as `Alice` and will not have `self.city` attribute attached.

Comment: This isn't a sane class structure. If anything, a child class should override the behaviour of a base class; a base class shouldn't alter its behaviour because it's being extended, and most certainly not based on how it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the current class when setting the property using `self.__class__.__name__`:

```py
class A():
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'Alice'
    if self.__class__.__name__ == 'A':
      self.city = 'Pittsburgh'

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    super(B, self).__init__()

x = A()
y = B()

print(hasattr(x, 'name'), hasattr(x, 'city'))
print(hasattr(y, 'name'), hasattr(y, 'city'))
```